# No indentation for first level enumeration

Tags: indentation, enumerate

I usually use enumerations like this:

```
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\arabic{enumi})}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\alph{enumii})}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{\roman{enumii})}

Hello world hello world

\begin{enumerate}
  \item First level item
  \item First level item
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Second level item Second level item Second level item Second level item Second level item Second level item Second level item Second level item Second level item 
    \item Second level item
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item Third level item
      \item Third level item
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

**Question**: How to set the indentation for first level items to zero, and how to make second and third level indentations non-zero, but smaller than their current default value?

PS: I'd like to keep the `enumerate` environment (if possible), and use built-in features instead of a new package.

[image]

Comment: But do you want the labels of first level `enumerate`s to stick into the left margin, or do you simply want them to be left-aligned?

Comment: @GuM I'm not sure: what is the difference between "stick to the left margin" and "left-aligned"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be possible without package, but I recommend using `enumitem` that provides for much greater flexibility.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{showframe,lipsum}% just for the example

\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\arabic*),leftmargin=*}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\alph*)}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{label=\roman*)}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[3]

\begin{enumerate}
  \item First level item
  \item First level item
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Second level item Second level item Second level item 
          Second level item Second level item Second level item
          Second level item Second level item Second level item 
    \item Second level item
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item Third level item
      \item Third level item
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @egreg. It worked well with `\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\arabic*),leftmargin=*}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\alph*),leftmargin=0.6cm}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{label=\roman*),leftmargin=0.55cm}` except for `ii) Third level item`, [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/U4hdC). How to have i) and ii) left-aligned and not aligned on the `)`?

Comment: @Basj Add `align=left` to the options for the third level. As you see, the flexibility of `enumitem` is very handy.

Comment: Thank you. A last [problem](https://imgur.com/a/npfx3): if there are more than 9 items, then the last `a)` won't be aligned on F of First level item. Why? I used `\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\arabic*),align=left,leftmargin=*}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\alph*),align=left,leftmargin=*}`.

Comment: @Basj I'm not sure what you're expecting. The a) *is* aligned; but you need to increase the label width if you plan to use more than nine items.